# How to make Expandable card?

Tags: listview, flutter

I am new to flutter and I want to make a list of cards like this.

[image]

I tried to Understand the original [Project](https://github.com/2d-inc/HistoryOfEverything) but I am not able to figure out.

I just want to make an expandable card without the background gif/video effect

Thanks...

Comment: You could do this by setting the height of your item with a variable and then updating it with setState, so that when the widget has been rebuild the height has changed.

Comment: You could look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50533285/8954451

Comment: How did you achieve the animation in the card background?

Answer (score 48):

try to add an `ExpansionTile` inside a `Card`, this will expand the `Card` when you expand the `ExpansionTile`

```
Card(
  child: Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: 36.0, left: 6.0, right: 6.0, bottom: 6.0),
      child: ExpansionTile(
      title: Text('Birth of Universe'),
        children: <Widget>[
         Text('Big Bang'),
         Text('Birth of the Sun'),
         Text('Earth is Born'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: It looks fine but is there any way to close the card clicking the extra area which comes after the expansion.

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean when the card in is expanded state if we click on the expanded area is there a way to close the card.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to use `ExpansionTile` then one of the easiest way of doing it is following:

```dart
class ExpandableCardContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isExpanded;
  final Widget collapsedChild;
  final Widget expandedChild;

  const ExpandableCardContainer(
      {Key key, this.isExpanded, this.collapsedChild, this.expandedChild})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExpandableCardContainerState createState() =>
      _ExpandableCardContainerState();
}

class _ExpandableCardContainerState extends State<ExpandableCardContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedContainer(
      duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      child: widget.isExpanded ? widget.expandedChild : widget.collapsedChild,
    );
  }
}
```

Use this widget and pass the collapsed child and expanded child and change the value of `isExpanded` on click of button or text.

```dart
 ExpandableCardContainer(
      expandedChild: createExpandedColumn(context),
      collapsedChild: createCollapsedColumn(context),
      isExpanded: widget.model.isExpanded,
 )
```

Now change the value of `isExpanded` on click of icon/text:

```dart
GestureDetector(
  child: Icon(
    widget.model.isExpanded
        ? EvaIcons.chevronDownOutline
        : EvaIcons.chevronUpOutline,
    color: Colors.grey,
    size: 20,
  ),
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      widget.model.isExpanded =
          !widget.model.isExpanded;
    });
  },
 ),
)
```

Comment: I am trying to use this for a project but i get an error that in widget.model.isExpanded, model is not recognized. Any ideas?

Comment: model is nothing but an object defined in the widget class and it has isExpanded boolean variable.

Comment: Can you please share how model is to be implemented

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what I said in the comments on your question:

It contains a [Card](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Card-class.html) with a [Container](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) which contains a height, the height is updated when the Card is tapped because of the [InkWell](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)'s onTap event, the onTap calls the [setState()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) function to update the widgets, with the new height of the Card.

```
   class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      double oldheight = 100.0;
      double newheight = 200.0;
      double height = 200.0;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final title = 'Basic List';

        return MaterialApp(
          title: title,
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(title),
            ),
            body: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (height == oldheight) {
                        height = newheight;
                      }
                      else{
                        height = oldheight;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                  child: Card(
                    child:Container(height: height,),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

*This isn't tested yet...*

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted maybe because you used StatefulWidget and clicking one card will affect other cards as well.

Comment: That shouldn't matter because a downvote marks it as not useful and it could be useful.