# How to Expand and collpase the Container in the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class SoloPage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SoloPageState createState() => _SoloPageState();
}

class _SoloPageState extends State<SoloPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text("Solo"),
       backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
     ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      height: 220,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
           Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.orange,
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                 topLeft: Radius.circular(50)
               )
             ),
              height: 35,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),

            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(

              color: Colors.blueGrey.shade800,
              ),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
              height: 150,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Date",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          Text("12/10/20",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Time",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          Text("12:30 PM",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Map",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          Text("Erangle",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Mode",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          Text("TPP",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Players Joined",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          Text("25",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[

                          Text("Winning Prizes",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                              Text(""),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Remaining Players",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          Text("75",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Per Kill",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          Text("₹ 10",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Entry Fees",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                          Text("₹ 20",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 185),
              height: 35,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(50)),
              color: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
              ),
              child: Center(
                  child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  print("Solo Joined");
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Join Contest",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25,
                    fontFamily: "OpenSans",
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have done the above code to create and design the container and on clicking on the container i want to expand that container and then by clicking on the same text i want to expand that container. There is text Winning Prizes in the container and by clicking on that i want to expand that container.

[Image of the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCimE.jpg)

Comment: do you want to expand when you tap on `join contest`?

Comment: You can use `AnimatedContainer`..read [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Expandable card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986328/how-to-make-expandable-card)

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61206640/4788260)

Comment: Adnan karim      YES

Comment: Sanjay Sharma Nope not like that

Comment: There is a lot way to do it actually, AnimatedContainer is the most clean way or you can make make two containers in column and use a bool to change second one's height from 0 to anything you want or you can use visibility for second one.

Comment: I have tried that here i am getting an wrost error so i have removed that code

Comment: Can you do it in the same code