# Make widget shows on tapping another widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, animation

I'm working on a Flutter app that shows smart home devices in each room that looks something like this

[image]

When I tap on the picture of the room, I want to make the part in the red circle appear right below it but I have no idea how is this kind of animation is called.

I'm using ListView for the part in the circle and InkWell for the picture.

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**
After following the suggestion from the comments (thank you) I found this package
https://pub.dev/packages/expandable
super easy to use, very intuitive. I would recommend anyone that's trying to create this expandable card to check it out

Comment: Should it be at the bottom of the screen... If so I would recommend a MODALBOTTOMSHEET.

Comment: It should appear right below the picture that has been tapped. Like if I tap the bedroom, the listview should appear between bedroom and kitchen.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this out... There are several solutions here to reaching your goal
[How to make Expandable card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54986328/how-to-make-expandable-card)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you put the devices list in an `AnimatedContainer` like that :

```
AnimatedContainer(
   height: isKitchenOpened ? 400 : 0,
   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
   child: Placeholder(),
)
```

`isKitchenOpened` being a boolean that you toggle when tapping the kitchen picture.

You can also change the animation curve, like `curve: Curves.decelerate`