# How to add a card in mid of any listview item - flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart

[I am trying to do like this (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0XGk.png) I am trying create a blog page, there I need some instant modifications (admin side) in ListView itself.

I [tried (code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530152/how-to-create-expandable-listview-in-flutter)... Expandable ListView - it is taking time to load and scroll as well - which contained Textfield and some buttons in it (update, Remove, and Cancel)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpandableList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExpandableListState createState() => _ExpandableListState();
}

class _ExpandableListState extends State<ExpandableList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return new ExpansionTile(
              title: new Text('item$i', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
              children: <Widget>[
                new Column(
                  children: [TextField(),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.update), onPressed: null),
                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: null),
                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.cancel), onPressed: null)
                    ],
                  )],
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And my requirement is to get that card below of an item on which I click (only) otherwise it should not be pre build with that list of items.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: @gianlucaparadise updated the code, please check.