# Flutter: Class for listview and expansionTile

Tags: flutter, user-interface, listview, expandablelistview

i am following the suggested solution from [How to create Expandable ListView in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530152/how-to-create-expandable-listview-in-flutter) as below:

```
void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,),);

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: vehicles.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return new ExpansionTile(
            title: new Text(vehicles[i].title, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),),
            children: <Widget>[
              new Column(
                children: _buildExpandableContent(vehicles[i]),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildExpandableContent(Vehicle vehicle) {
    List<Widget> columnContent = [];

    for (String content in vehicle.contents)
      columnContent.add(
        new ListTile(
          title: new Text(content, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
          leading: new Icon(vehicle.icon),
        ),
      );

    return columnContent;
  }
}

class Vehicle {
  final String title;
  List<String> contents = [];
  final IconData icon;

  Vehicle(this.title, this.contents, this.icon);
}

List<Vehicle> vehicles = [
  new Vehicle(
    'Bike',
    ['Vehicle no. 1', 'Vehicle no. 2', 'Vehicle no. 7', 'Vehicle no. 10'],
    Icons.motorcycle,
  ),
  new Vehicle(
    'Cars',
    ['Vehicle no. 3', 'Vehicle no. 4', 'Vehicle no. 6'],
    Icons.directions_car,
  ),
];
```

How to modify  the "class Vehicle" to add info like year and color?
The year and color info will be use "onTap" to show/use in new screen

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*To Add year and Color to the class Modify Your Vehicle Class like below,*

```
class Vehicle {
  final String title;
  List<String> contents = [];
  final IconData icon;
  int year;
  Color vehicleColor;

  Vehicle({this.title, this.contents, this.icon, this.year, this.vehicleColor});
}
```

It is good to Make your **Constructor Parameters** `Named Parameters` to avoid confusion later, or You can also make them `Positional parameters`.

For More Info on Named Parameters and Optional Parameters **check** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264230/what-is-the-difference-between-named-and-positional-parameters-in-dart).

*Now You Can Easily Add data to your list*

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles = [
  new Vehicle(
    title: 'Bike',
    contents: [
      'Vehicle no. 1',
      'Vehicle no. 2',
      'Vehicle no. 7',
      'Vehicle no. 10'
    ],
    icon: Icons.motorcycle,
    year: 2018,
    vehicleColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
  new Vehicle(
    title: 'Bike',
    contents: [
      'Vehicle no. 1',
      'Vehicle no. 2',
      'Vehicle no. 7',
      'Vehicle no. 10'
    ],
    icon: Icons.motorcycle,
    year: 2019,
    vehicleColor: Colors.red,
  ),
];
```

And When You Want to add the data into the list then simply call this line of code,
in the onTap method

```
  vehicles.add(Vehicle(
    title: 'Bike',
    contents: [
      'Vehicle no. 1',
      'Vehicle no. 2',
      'Vehicle no. 7',
      'Vehicle no. 10'
    ],
    icon: Icons.motorcycle,
    year: 2018,
    vehicleColor: Colors.blue,
  ));
```