# Flutter Expandable in Dropdownmenu

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, expandable

I am trying to do a Dropdown menu with expandable Items inside.
I also got it working somehow but I am not sure if this the best way to do it.

I want a similar UI to this. A dropdown menu

[image]

that transforms into this.

[image]

What I did looks like this until now.

[image]

And on click this happens

[image]

[image]

So I got a somehow working Prototype. My issue is the icons like the dropdownmenu arrow icon, the "X" and "+" icons. Like for Example right now I am hiding the dropdown menu arrow because it overlaps with the "+" icon. Also the DropdownMenuItem is not a String but a PanleItem. so I can expand the list without opening the DropdownMenu.

I can't get it to work on the different stages.
I hope I can get some help here or someone can add some references to helpful Articles etc..

This is my Code till now.

```
 import 'package:expandable/expandable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomExandableDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomExandableDropDownState createState() =>
      _CustomExandableDropDownState();
}

class _CustomExandableDropDownState extends State<CustomExandableDropDown> {
  late String itemName;
  late List<PanelItem> _data;
  int currentIndex = 0;
  List<String> items = ["first", "second", "third"];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _data = generateItems(items.length);
    itemName = _data.first.itemName;
  }

  List<PanelItem> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
    return List<PanelItem>.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
      return PanelItem(
        itemName: items[index],
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            left: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Color(0xFFACACAC),
            ),
            right: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Color(0xFFACACAC),
            ),
            top: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Color(0xFFACACAC),
            ),
            bottom: BorderSide(
              width: 1,
              color: Color(0xFFACACAC),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
          child: Container(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: itemName,
              isExpanded: true,
              icon: Container(),
              underline: Container(),
              items: _data.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: item.itemName,
                  child: ExpandablePanel(
                      theme: ExpandableThemeData(
                          hasIcon: false, tapHeaderToExpand: true),
                      header: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text(item.itemName),
                          Icon(Icons.add),
                        ],
                      ),
                      collapsed: Container(),
                      expanded: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              item.itemName,
                              softWrap: true,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              item.itemName,
                              softWrap: true,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              item.itemName,
                              softWrap: true,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String? value) {
                if (value != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    itemName = value;
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PanelItem {
  PanelItem({
    required this.itemName,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String itemName;
  bool isExpanded;
}
```

Comment: i believe that ui isnot using dropdown, it's just inserting another layout based on condition inside list.

Comment: Yeah, i tried to do that with the dropdown widget, but that didn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

[ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) and [ExpansionPanel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html) might just be what you are looking for with many example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530152/how-to-create-expandable-listview-in-flutter)

Comment: I know how to do the expansion, I am already doing it. But I want to combine it with a dropdownmenu.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want to do you can use Expansion tile. I have something similar on a project which I'm currently working on. see if you can try and customize it for yourself:

```
//items is list of things which you want to include under each tile for example your //Rinnen Rinnenhalten .....
ExpansionTile(
      trailing: Text(
        'See all',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
      ),
      title: Text('Categories'),
      children: [
        Wrap(
          children: [
            for (var i in items)
              Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 50,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => BasedOnCats(i.toString())));
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(i.toString()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Thx for the code but this is not my issue. I want to have an expansionTile Widget in a dropDownMenu. The expansion already works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply - you can put in your DropdownButtonFormField disabled DropdownMenuItem(s) that have children ExpansionTile(s) that have children ListTile(s) which you onTap, you can save the value.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension OnStringNull on String? {
  Widget get w {
    return Text(this ?? '');
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(body: MyForm()),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  final String name;
  List<Item>? subItems;
  Item(this.name, [this.subItems]);

  @override
  String toString() => name;
}

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyForm> createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  final List<Item> items = [
    Item('Ein', [Item('Einstein'), Item('Eintopf')]),
    Item('Zwei', [Item('Zweigeltrebe'), Item('Zweigeltrebe rose')]),
    Item('Drei', [Item('Dreich'), Item('Dreidel')]),
    Item('Führ - no subitems'),
    Item('Fümf - no subitems too')
  ];

  List<Item> selectedMulti = [];
  Item? selectedSingle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        DropdownButtonFormField<Item>(
          isExpanded: true,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
          hint: const Text('Choose something'),
          items: items.map((e) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<Item>(
              enabled: false,
              value: e,
              child: e.subItems==null? ListTile(title: '$e'.w,  onTap: () {
                            selectedMulti.add(e);
                            selectedSingle = e;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            setState(() {});
                          },): ExpansionTile(
                title: '$e'.w,
                children: listWrap(
                    e.subItems,
                    (index, f) => ListTile(
                          onTap: () {
                            selectedMulti.add(f);
                            selectedSingle = f;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          title: '$f'.w,
                        )),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {},
          value: null, // Musí zůstat null
        ),
        'Single selection: $selectedSingle'.w,
        'Multi Selection: $selectedMulti'.w,
     
        ElevatedButton(child: 'Delete'.w, onPressed:(){
          selectedMulti.clear();
          selectedSingle = null;
          setState((){});
        }),
      ],
          );
  }
}

   /// just generate new list based on old iterable and wraps items in new wrap
  List<E> listWrap<E, F>(
      Iterable<F>? iterable, E Function(int index, F item) f) {
    if (iterable == null) return [];
    List<E> tmp = [];
    int ind = 0;
    for (var e in iterable) {
      tmp.add(f(ind++, e));
    }
    return tmp;
  }
```