# Flutter Items inside ExpansionTile inside ListView are not scrollable

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to place a ExpansionTile inside a nested ListView Builder. Unfortunately despite all attempts I am unable to make the ListView items inside the ExpansionTile scrollable.

Kind of attempted to use ClampPhysics and NeverClampPhysics but dont seem to work.

Any ideas how I can get that done? Any pointers? Am I doing anything wrong?

Here is the code.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column (
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    child: Text(' Sunrise : '+DateFormat.jms().format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(yamistart))),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Text(' Sunset : '+DateFormat.jms().format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(yamiset))),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Card(
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: paksList == null ? 0 : paksList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                 /* Custom Code Here */
                  return Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    elevation: 8.0,
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: (yfrom >= valnow || valnow >= yto) ? Color.fromRGBO(40, 75, 50, .9) : Color.fromRGBO(9, 72, 135, .9), border: Border.all(color: (yfrom >= valnow || valnow >= yto) ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.lightBlue)),
                      child: (yfrom >= valnow || valnow >= yto) ? ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                        title: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              
                                    Text(
                                "Current Rhythm",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ), 
                            ]),
                        trailing: (yfrom >= valnow || valnow >= yto) ? null : Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded) ,
                      ) : ExpansionTile(
                        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),

                        title: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              
                                    Text(
                                "Current Rhythm",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ), 
                            ])),
                      children: [
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: TestList == null ? 0 : TestList.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                          /* Custom Code */
                              if (color == "Red"){
                                myColor = Colors.red;
                              }
                              else if (color == "Green"){
                                myColor = Colors.lightGreenAccent;
                              }
                              else {
                                myColor = Colors.yellow;
                              }

                              if (index ==0){
                                yfroms = yfrom;

                                ytos = yfroms+ duration*60*1000;
                              }

                              else{
                                yfroms = ytos;

                                ytos = ytos+duration*60*1000;
                              }

                              return Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                ),
                                elevation: 8.0,
                                margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: myColor, border: Border.all(color: Colors.lightBlue)),
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
                                    title: Container(
                              child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                            Text(
                                "Current Rhythm : Silence ",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),  
                                        ]),


                                  ),
                                ),
                              ));
                            },)
                      ],
                      //  trailing: (yfrom >= valnow || valnow >= yto) ? null : Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded) ,
                      ),

                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )])),
);
```

Comment: What about setting `Card`'s `LsitView` to `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ExpandableListView` widget for scrolling your listView.
Below link will helpful to you for creating that widget.

[Create enpandable listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530152/how-to-create-expandable-listview-in-flutter)