# I want to create menu which can be expanded and can have some sort of details

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, widget, expansion-tile

[image: OpenMenu]

Need to develop like above image, which can have some sort of texts, icons, trailing icons and other information as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a List of `ExpansionTiles` for an example, look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540183/13755145